# Fluxbox keyboard layout keys shortcut problem

Tags: fluxbox

I added this line to my ~/.fluxbox/keys file:

```
Mod1 Shift :ToggleCmd {Exec setxkbmap fr} {Exec setxkbmap us}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`Mod1` is the <kbd>Alt</kbd> Key and a so called modifier key. You can print the other modifier keys with `$ xmodmap -pm`. As you can see, <kbd>Shift</kbd> is just another modifier. Fluxbox is not able to recognize such a key combination. But it will work, if you use the "real" keyname, as printed by `$ xmodmap -pm`.